# Why is this inline?

Tags: html, css, display

I dont understand why the divs are shown inline, if they are set to block, shouldnt the first div be on top of the second? Why are they beeing displayed next to each other instead on top of each other? Thanks for your help.

```css
div.pagination {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div.pagination li {
  display: block;
}
div.pagination li a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Simple Pagination</h2>
<div class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: this is likely due to the `float: left` that you're applying to your anchor tags. Remove that and you'l notice your `div`s are no longer side-by-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div.pagination {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div.pagination li {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.pagination li a {
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Simple Pagination</h2>
<div class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: Explain please!